# Random Intercept Cross Lagged Panel Model (RI-CLPM) in R

Tags: r, syntax, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

I am hoping to run a RI-CLPM in R using three variables. Authors of this paper (Mond & Nestler, 2017) have graciously made the syntax (below) available for two variable model.

I'm having some difficulty moving beyond adding 3 additional stability and lagged paths--I would appreciate help in modifying the code to incorporate a third variable.

```
  ## load data
data <- read.table("./data/Fakedata_RI-CLPM_R.dat", header = T)

## Define model for lavaan
riclpm <- '
# Define intercept factors
ix =~ 1*x1+1*x2+1*x3+1*x4
iy =~ 1*y1+1*y2+1*y3+1*y4

# Define phantom latent variables
etax1 =~ 1*x1
etax2 =~ 1*x2
etax3 =~ 1*x3
etax4 =~ 1*x4

etay1 =~ 1*y1
etay2 =~ 1*y2
etay3 =~ 1*y3
etay4 =~ 1*y4

# Autoregressive effects
etax2 ~ a1*etax1
etax3 ~ a1*etax2
etax4 ~ a1*etax3

etay2 ~ a2*etay1
etay3 ~ a2*etay2
etay4 ~ a2*etay3

# Crosslagged effects
etay2 ~ c1*etax1
etay3 ~ c1*etax2
etay4 ~ c1*etax3

etax2 ~ c2*etay1
etax3 ~ c2*etay2
etax4 ~ c2*etay3

# Some further constraints on the variance structure
# 1. Set error variances of the observed variables to zero
x1 ~~ 0*x1
x2 ~~ 0*x2
x3 ~~ 0*x3
x4 ~~ 0*x4

y1 ~~ 0*y1
y2 ~~ 0*y2
y3 ~~ 0*y3
y4 ~~ 0*y4

# 2. Let lavaan estimate the variance of the latent variables
etax1 ~~ varx1*etax1
etax2 ~~ varx2*etax2
etax3 ~~ varx3*etax3
etax4 ~~ varx4*etax4

etay1 ~~ vary1*etay1
etay2 ~~ vary2*etay2
etay3 ~~ vary3*etay3
etay4 ~~ vary4*etay4

# 3. We also want estimates of the intercept factor variances and an
#    estimate of their covariance
ix ~~ varix*ix
iy ~~ variy*iy
ix ~~ covi*iy

# 4. We have to define that the covariance between the intercepts 
and
#    the latents of the first time point are zero
etax1 ~~ 0*ix
etay1 ~~ 0*ix
etax1 ~~ 0*iy
etay1 ~~ 0*iy

# 5. Finally, we estimate the covariance between the latents of x 
and y
#    of the first time point, the second time-point and so on. note 
that
#    for the second to fourth time point the correlation is 
  constrained to
#    the same value
etax1 ~~ cov1*etay1
etax2 ~~ e1*etay2
etax3 ~~ e1*etay3
etax4 ~~ e1*etay4

# The model also contains a mean structure and we have to define 
some
# constraints for this part of the model. the assumption is that we
# only want estimates of the mean of the intercept factors. all 
other means
# are defined to be zero:
x1 ~ 0*1
x2 ~ 0*1
x3 ~ 0*1
x4 ~ 0*1
y1 ~ 0*1
y2 ~ 0*1
y3 ~ 0*1
y4 ~ 0*1

etax1 ~ 0*1
etax2 ~ 0*1
etax3 ~ 0*1
etax4 ~ 0*1

etay1 ~ 0*1
etay2 ~ 0*1
etay3 ~ 0*1
etay4 ~ 0*1

ix ~ 1
iy ~ 1


## define correlations
cori := covi / (sqrt(varix) * sqrt(variy))
cor1 := cov1 / (sqrt(varx1) * sqrt(vary1))
cort2 := e1 / (sqrt(varx2) * sqrt(vary2))
cort3 := e1 / (sqrt(varx3) * sqrt(vary4))
cort4 := e1 / (sqrt(varx4) * sqrt(vary4))'
```